# Storing data in a data frame

Tags: python, r, pandas, dataframe

New to python I'm struggling with a way to combine operation on my raw data and a way to store them in a data frame and then using it again with pandas and R.

some example of my code:

```
if 'Subject' in f:
     for i in range (len(time)):
          (...)
                    if  Description[j] == 'response':  
                        RT.append(time[j] - time_stim)
                        motor_time.append(time[j] - time_response)                
                        break
```

My raw data is a .txt file example below:

```
Type,Description,Time,Channel 
Categorie,PC,153,1,All 
Stimulus,S11,1510,1,All 
Stimulus,S202,3175,1,All 
Stimulus,EMG_Onset,3978,1,EMGL 
Stimulus,response,4226,1,All 
Categorie,CC,5785,1,All 
Stimulus,S11,7141,1,All 
Stimulus,S202,8807,1,All 
Stimulus,EMG_Onset,9549,1,EMGL
Stimulus,EMG_Onset,9965,1,EMGL 
Stimulus,response,10249,1,All
```

In this example, I want to store RT or motor_time which I got from this piece of code in a yet non-existent data frame to use it first with python then with R. This data frame would have to store all parameters for all my experimental conditions and subject

In this case, all results are stored in numeric np.array and I don't know how to use them with specific R code I created before.

Thanks.

Comment: In what format are your 'raw' data? Please post an example. Why do you insist on mixing python and R (which is certainly possible, but what do you need it for)?

Comment: Strongly second lanenok's suggestion.  Don't mix 2 different languages unless you need to, it is inevitably more complicated.  Just pick one or the other and go from there.  To the extent you do want to share dataframes between them, both R and pandas will read/write HDF5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found an easy way, I probably didn't know what to search and how to ask, but here is my solution:

```
df_trans = pd.DataFrame({'Sujet': np.array(subj_id),
                   'Temps_moteur': np.array(motor_time),
                   'TR' : np.array(RT),
                   ...})
```

and to save it and use it in R :

```
df_trans.to_csv('x.csv')
```

Thank you Pandas !

Answer (score 1):

I should first say, that I do not see any reason for you to mix python and R.

If you have your analysis already in R, you can directly read your TXT file into R data frame

```
df = read.csv("myfile.txt")
head(df)  # to display the first few rows of your data frame
```

Your 1st, 2nd and 5th columns will be converted to factors (you can change it if you desired).

If you want python, you can read your file into pandas DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("myfile.txt")
df.head()  # to display the first few rows of your data frame
```

If this is not a solution for your question, please indicate what do you want beyond this?

There is a [rpy](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/) package which allows you to use R code in python. It requires extra python programming code anyway.

As to importing pandas data frame into R: I would save it into CSV file or other format (save as "save on hard disk") and then open in R. But CSV file is what you initially get, so no point for you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The solution I was searching ffor was to extract all the object printed by the actual python code (like in this example RT or Motor_time for this description) in a df and then to import it in R, but I didn't find any solutions that don't need to re-write the code using Pandas.
But I will try to re-write the python code with pandas and learn to use it at the same time, it seems to be the best solution, and perhaps I will then be able to perform all the calculus with python.

Comment: What do you mean by "printed by the actual python code"?  Using pandas is also "actual python code". Your example is not clear becaues f, time, RT, motor_time are not  defined. Anyway, if your goal is to achieve result - go with R. If you want to have fun with python, go for python and pandas.

Comment: For this time I go for results, but for the next set of data with less time pressure I surely will use python. Thank you for your help.